# What authentication mechanism to use in client app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC client application. User is authenticated and authorized via another API application which returns token.

Currently, after client app recieves token from API, it saves token in session and sets form authentication cookie for app authorization.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(TokenViewModel.Username, rememberMe);
HttpContext.Current.Session["AuthenticationToken"] = TokenViewModel;
```

Should i keep using form authentication, or just save token in session? or user OWIN here to authorize user.

Client app uses [Authorize] attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [Authorize] attribute, by default the API will check for the access token in the Authorization header of the HTTP request, not in the cookie.

If you want to use the cookie, then go for forms authentication or customize the Authorize attribute to check for the token inside the cookie.

So, it's better to keep the token in session and at the same time manage it's lifetime(token expiry) explicitly. Apart from that, you can use refresh tokens to get new access token after or before the current one expires.

Comment: Question is for client app. API is using token to authorize, what authentication for client app is better?

Comment: Using cookies would be better.